# get foreignId Data from the feed of a user [Stream Js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, getstream-io

hi i'm trying to implement getstream.io in my project.

i'm using https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js

as my server side script is in nodeJS.

i'm able to create a user in feed using

```
user1 = client.feed('user', 'dpz');
```

i'm creating activity for this user using using

```
activity ={
         "actor":"user:1",
         "message": "@flat_4_bfcaffca-c35f-11e5-8080-8001002e75f6",
         "verb":"tweet",
         "object":"tweet:4",
         "foreign_id": "flat:4"
         };
user1.addActivity(activity);
```

if i want to get all records of that user,
i use

```
user1.get()
.then(function(body) { console.log(JSON.stringify(body)); })
.catch(function(reason) { console.log(JSON.stringify(reason.error));});
```

i get result as :

```
{"duration":"19ms",
"next":"",
"results":[{
        "actor":"user:1",
        "foreign_id":"flat:4",
        "id":"41231d40-ca5a-11e5-8080-800047dac62a",
        "message":"@flat_4_bfcaffca-c35f-11e5-8080-8001002e75f6",
        "object":"tweet:4",
        "origin":null,
        "target":null,
        "time":"2016-02-03T09:41:09.335584",
        "to":[],
        "verb":"tweet"
    }]
}
```

in your rest_ documentation
https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#feed_detail

you have specified

```
feed/(feed_slug)/(user_id)/(activity_id|foreign_id)/
```

to delete an activity for if the foreign key matches criteria.
in your nodejs code

```
user1.removeActivity({foreignId: 'flat:4'})
```

line works to remove the feed for that user where foreign key is flat:4

```
user1.get({foreignId: 'flat:4'})
```

does not work
can you please help if i want to get feeds with the foreignId as 'flat:4'

is there any way for such ?
please help as i'm stuck on this point only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `feed/(feed_slug)/(user_id)/(activity_id|foreign_id)/` endpoint is only for `DELETE` requests. At this present is not possible to retrieve activities by its `foreign_id`. That field can only be used to perform cascaded deletion and/or to define the uniqueness of your data.

Looking at the code that you added, it seems like to use references to feeds as the value for `foreign_id`s, if that's the case then you are probably using this field in a weird/wrong way and you should create a new question on SO to ask help with the integration of your data.

Comment: thanks for the response.. will do a work around.

just wanted to know whether we can use foreignId as an end point

because in stream-js, src/lib/feed.js file i came across the snippet.

`removeActivity: function(activityId, callback) {
var identifier = (activityId.foreignId) ? activityId.foreignId : activityId;
var params = {};
if (activityId.foreignId) {
 params['foreign_id'] = '1';
}
return this.client.delete({
 url: 'feed/' + this.feedUrl + '/' + identifier + '/',
 qs: params,
 signature: this.signature,
},callback);
},`

i tried to change also 

`this.client.delete` to `this.client.get`